# SSIS Script Task C# Only assignment and new object expressions can be used Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I'm using a C# Script task in SSIS to check the file size of a file and compare to a variable called `FileFoundSize` .  This is my code:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(Dts.Variables["$Project::ValidationImport"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["User::zipFileName"].Value.ToString());
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fullPath);

        if (fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            fileInfo.Length > Dts.Variables["User::FileFoundSize"];
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            // file could not be found     
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }
```

However, the editor keeps highlighting this line:

```
fileInfo.Length > Dts.Variables["User::FileFoundSize"];
```

And stating this error:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: You are calling the property like a method: `fileInfo.Exists()` should be `fileInfo.Exists` (without the `()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code, you missed Value property for variable

```
if (fileInfo.Exists)
{
        if(fileInfo.Length > Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["User::FileFoundSize"].Value.ToString()))
           Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        else
           Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
}
else
{
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
}
```

Comment: I then receive the error: Operator > cannot be applied to operands of type long and object

Comment: check now, appended ToString()

Comment: In Variable declartion tab, i hope you would declared  FileFoundSize variable as Int or string

Comment: FileFoundSize variable is INT

Comment: I now received error: Operator > cannot be applied to operands of type long and string

Comment: check now, used Convert.ToInt32 to convert to intger value of variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216754/discussion-between-mudassir-hasan-and-michael).